# ReactJS history push not passing state to all the components

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use history push passing a state to my components but it's not working properly.

What happens is:

1. The location props is not being passed to all the components
2. If I refresh (F5) the screen, then the location props will be populated with the values I sent from the screen before

Now here's the code for my App.js render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" render={props => <Header {...props} token={this.state.token} username={this.state.username}  />} />
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Marketplace key="marketplace" {...props}  />} />
          <Route path="/login" render={props => <Login {...props} updateUsernameAndToken={this.updateUsernameAndToken} />} />
          <Route path="/create-account/*" render={props => <CreateAccount {...props} />} />   
          <Route path="/" render={props => <Footer {...props} />} /> 
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Into the Login component, that's how I'm pushing it to the next do the login:

```
marketplace = (username, token) => {
        console.log("Inside marketplace with username: " + username + " and token: " + token);
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: "/",
            state: {
                username: username,
                token: token
            }
        });
    }
```

The component that is rendered without the location properly is Header.
The one that prints the location props properly is Marketplace.

The flow I'm doing is:
I access localhost:3000 (So I display Header, Marketplace and Footer)
Then I click in a Login link, that does a push to /login

```
goToCreateAccount = () => {
        this.props.history.push("/create-account/profile");
    }
```

That's being done into the HeaderTop component. 
Here the render for my Header component:

```
render(){
        const currentState = this.state;

        let content;
        if(currentState.loading){
            content = <div className="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
        }else{
            content =
                <div className="sticky-top">
                    <HeaderTop {...this.props} userInfo={this.state} />
                    <HeaderBottom userInfo={this.state}  />
                </div>
        }
        return content;
    }
```

What am I missing that is making the location.state props not be displayed into the Header, but being displayed into Marketplace?

If I ask to print this.props inside the Header.render method is doesn't return the location.state and the location.path is still /login instead of /
When I do a refresh, then both location.path and location.state are displayed properly.

Comment: Have you tried with import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
history.push(‘/login’) or this.context.history.push('/path'); ?

Comment: Yes. none of them worked.